# How to use Case-When and Update in Trigger?(Error in my code)

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

I tried to create below Trigger but I have an Error.
Can I Use Update or use 'case when' in trigger?
Please help me to fix my issue here.

Code Explanation:
I want to update my existing row after insert or update.
Do not change the 'FUSDate1' or 'FUSDate2' If I didn't  add anything to the 'FUSDate1' or 'FUSDate2'

Update the FUSDate to the New One or Inserted one If I Updated or inserted data to FUSDate

Code:

```
delimiter //

create trigger SafetyCertificationTRG
after insert on SafetyCertification
for each row
begin
    case when (FUSDate1='' or FUZDate1 is NULL) then (FUZDate1=OLD.FUSDate1)  else (update SafetyCertification set FUZDate1=NEW.FUSDate1) end;
    case when (FUSDate2='' or FUZDate2 is NULL) then (FUZDate2=NEW.FUSDate2) else (update SafetyCertification set FUZDate2=NEW.FUSDate2) end;
end //

delimiter ;
```

Edit: I am going to add some information here to make the question more clear.

I have one column as FUS that can be get these 3 values only:('FUS1', 'FUS2' and 'FUS3')
I have 3 other columns: FUSDate1, FUSDate2, FUSDate3.

I want to save the Current Date to The FUSDate1 Or FUSDate2 Or FUSDate3 based on the user User Selection of FUS. (They are in same Table)

I used the provided answer and change it to this but I cannot do the above.

Code: This code is just for FUS1 and FUSDate1

```
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER  SafetyCertification_bu
BEFORE UPDATE ON   SafetyCertification
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   -- detect a change made to a value in col
   IF OLD.FUS <=> NEW.FUS THEN
      -- value of col is not changed, so do nothing
      DO 0;
   ELSE
      -- we detected a new value was assigned to col
      IF OLD.FUS ='%FUS1%' THEN
         -- we can override the new value, keep it the same
         SET NEW.FUSDate1 = CURDATE();
      END IF;
   END IF;
END //

delimiter ;
```

Another code that I expected to do my work but still have problem, Does not update Like above Code:

```
delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER  SafetyCertification_bu
BEFORE INSERT ON   SafetyCertification
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.FUS='%FUS1%' THEN
         SET new.FUSDate1=MD5(CURDATE());
    END IF;

END //

delimiter ;
```

Update 3:

The Third code that provided in answer does not add anything to the FUSdate1 and 2 and 3 when i update or insert any data.

Code

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER  SafetyCertification_bu
BEFORE UPDATE ON   SafetyCertification
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   -- set one of the `fusdateN` columns to current date
   -- which column to set depends on the value assigned to `fus` 
   IF NEW.fus = 'FUS1' THEN
      SET NEW.fusdate1 = DATE(NOW());
   ELSEIF NEW.fus = 'FUS2' THEN
      SET NEW.fusdate2 = DATE(NOW());
   ELSEIF NEW.fus = 'FUS3' THEN
      SET NEW.fusdate3 = DATE(NOW());
   END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You cannot modify the contents of a table involved in the query that initiated the trigger; especially the table the trigger is on.

Comment: I had a same question before. Good question

Comment: @Uueerdo So What should I do for this case? Do you have any recommendation?

Comment: @kiarash Did you able to find any solution?

Comment: @christiano  I found a silly and low performance solution, I create two triggers, one to another table and I create the second trigger to insert the data in the first table. Not sure if there is any other way

Comment: @Christiano you'll need multiple queries outside of a trigger; it can be done in the procedural language of the process that executed the query you're triggering off of, or the initiating query can be replaced with a stored procedure that performs that query and any followup queries needed.

Comment: some notes: in equality comparison, percent characters in a literal are  literal characters, not wildcards as they are in a a `LIKE` comparison. That is, `'abc' = '%abc%'` evaluates to 0 (false), `'abc' LIKE '%abc%'` evaluates to 1 (true).  The last example introduces the `MD5` function, no rationale given for using that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of notes:

A trigger cannot issue an UPDATE against the table that fired the trigger, this is prohibited.

The unqualified references (e.g. `FUSDate1` and `FUZDate1`) are not valid. Those references don't resolve to anything.

The reference to `OLD.FUSDate1` is invalid in the context of an AFTER INSERT trigger.  In an UPDATE trigger, the `OLD.col` refers to the value of col before the update.

The expression `(FUZDate1=OLD.FUSDate1)` is not an assignment, it's a comparison that's going to return 0, 1 or NULL.

If we want to trigger on an `UPDATE` and an `INSERT`, that will require two separate triggers.

If we want to modify the contents of the current row, we can use `BEFORE` trigger instead of `AFTER`.

---

*I want to update my existing row after insert or update.*

It would be much easier to apply changes *before* the row is inserted or updated. We can assign a value to a column `col` by referencing `NEW.col` in an assignment in a `BEFORE INSERT` or `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger.  For example:

```
 SET NEW.col = expr;
```

---

*Do not change the `FUSDate1` or `FUSDate2` If I didn't add anything to the `FUSDate1` or `FUSDate2`*

This seems pretty straightforward. Just don't make any assignments to `NEW.FUSDate1` or `NEW.FUSDate2`.

---

*Update the FUSDate to the New One or Inserted one If I Updated or inserted data to FUSDate*

The example proposed trigger contains references to `FUZDate1` or `FUZDate2`, but there's no mention of these columns in the specification. The specification is confusing.

An `UPDATE` statement will assign a value to a column, no need for a trigger to do that. An `INSERT` statement can assign a value to a column, again, no need for a trigger for that.

---

The specification is not clear. Providing example starting state (rows in the table), and example INSERT or UPDATE statements, and the desired state after the statement is executed would go a long ways towards clarifying the requirements.

A demonstration of a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger that prevents a new value being assigned to a particular column:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER  SafetyCertification_bu
BEFORE UPDATE ON   SafetyCertification
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   -- detect a change made to a value in col
   IF OLD.col <=> NEW.col THEN
      -- value of col is not changed, so do nothing
      DO 0;
   ELSE
      -- we detected a new value was assigned to col
      IF OLD.col IS NOT NULL THEN
         -- we can override the new value, keep it the same
         SET NEW.col = OLD.col;
      END IF;
   END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

For what this example trigger achieves, we don't necessarily need that many `IF` conditions; those are included as a demonstrate some of the checks we can perform, how we can make references to the existing value of `col` and the new value assigned to `col`.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

Based on the update information in the question, here's an example of a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger that satisfies the specification.

This is for the `UPDATE` action. To get this same behavior with an `INSERT` statement, this trigger definition needs to be repeated, with `BEFORE INSERT` in place of `BEFORE UPDATE`.

(I would use the name `_bu` for the before update trigger, and `_bi` for before insert trigger.)

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER  SafetyCertification_bu
BEFORE UPDATE ON   SafetyCertification
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   -- set one of the `fusdateN` columns to current date
   -- which column to set depends on the value assigned to `fus` 
   IF NEW.fus = 'FUS1' THEN
      SET NEW.fusdate1 = DATE(NOW());
   ELSEIF NEW.fus = 'FUS2' THEN
      SET NEW.fusdate2 = DATE(NOW());
   ELSEIF NEW.fus = 'FUS3' THEN
      SET NEW.fusdate3 = DATE(NOW());
   END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**second followup**

To answer the question about using `CASE WHEN` statement in the context of a MySQL stored program...

We could implement the example trigger (directly above in this answer) replacing the `IF-THEM` with either of the two forms of the `CASE` statement.

*either*

```
   CASE 
      WHEN NEW.fus = 'FUS1' THEN
         SET NEW.fusdate1 = DATE(NOW());
      WHEN NEW.fus = 'FUS2' THEN
         SET NEW.fusdate2 = DATE(NOW());
      WHEN NEW.fus = 'FUS3' THEN
         SET NEW.fusdate3 = DATE(NOW());
   END CASE;
```

*-or-*

```
   CASE NEW.fus 
      WHEN 'FUS1' THEN
         SET NEW.fusdate1 = DATE(NOW());
      WHEN 'FUS2' THEN
         SET NEW.fusdate2 = DATE(NOW());
      WHEN 'FUS3' THEN
         SET NEW.fusdate3 = DATE(NOW());
   END CASE;
```

---

*note*

The `CASE` statement is available in MySQL stored programs; outside of a stored program, it is *not* a valid SQL statement.

Also, we should not confuse this CASE *statement* with the CASE *expression*. The CASE expression *is* valid in the context of a SQL statement, such as a `SELECT` or `UPDATE` statement.

**DEMONSTRATION**

*"I examined the Trigger, But unfortunately does not save anything in fusDates."*

@Christiano: here is a simple demonstration

create table

```
CREATE TABLE `safety_certification`
( id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
, fus       VARCHAR(5)
, fusdate1  DATE
, fusdate2  DATE
, fusdate3  DATE
) ENGINE=INNODB
;
```

populate table with demonstration rows

```
INSERT INTO `safety_certification` (id, fus, fusdate1, fusdate2, fusdate3) VALUES
( 1, '', NULL, NULL, NULL)
,( 2, '', NULL, NULL, NULL)
,( 3, '', NULL, NULL, NULL)
,( 4, '', NULL, NULL, NULL)
,( 5, '', NULL, NULL, NULL)
;
```

create trigger

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER  `safety_certification_bu`
BEFORE UPDATE ON   `safety_certification`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   -- set one of the `fusdateN` columns to current date
   -- which column to set depends on the value assigned to `fus`
   IF NEW.fus = 'FUS1' THEN
      SET NEW.fusdate1 = DATE(NOW());
   ELSEIF NEW.fus = 'FUS2' THEN
      SET NEW.fusdate2 = DATE(NOW());
   ELSEIF NEW.fus = 'FUS3' THEN
      SET NEW.fusdate3 = DATE(NOW());
   END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

updates will exercise BEFORE UPDATE trigger we just defined

```
UPDATE `safety_certification` sc SET sc.fus = 'FUS1' WHERE sc.id = 1 ;
UPDATE `safety_certification` sc SET sc.fus = 'FUS2' WHERE sc.id = 2 ;
UPDATE `safety_certification` sc SET sc.fus = 'FUS3' WHERE sc.id = 3 ;
UPDATE `safety_certification` sc SET sc.fus = 'FUS4' WHERE sc.id = 4 ;
```

display contents of table

```
SELECT * FROM `safety_certification`;
```

returns:

```
    id  fus     fusdate1    fusdate2    fusdate3
------  ------  ----------  ----------  ------------
     1  FUS1    2018-05-04  (NULL)      (NULL)
     2  FUS2    (NULL)      2018-05-04  (NULL)
     3  FUS3    (NULL)      (NULL)      2018-05-04
     4  FUS4    (NULL)      (NULL)      (NULL)
     5          (NULL)      (NULL)      (NULL)
```

seems like the trigger is populating the columns fusdate1, fusdate2 and fusdate3 per the specification, when some particular values are assigned to fus

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much,

Comment: I worked on it and I provided an edition in my question. I still have a problem.

Comment: FOLLOWUP is added to answer, provides example trigger definition that satisfies the specification given in the edits to question.

Comment: second followup added, to address question in the title, using `CASE WHEN` statement

Comment: Thank you so much for all helps, I really do appreciate for your time. I will work on it and will make it as a best answer. Please give me time to work on it.

Comment: I examined the Trigger, But unfortunately does not save anything in fusDates.

Comment: @Christiano: I appended a **DEMONSTRATION** to the answer, to show the BEFORE UPDATE trigger performing the operations that were specified.

Comment: Thank you so much, It seems I have problem with my MYSQL since it doesn't work properly.

Comment: I can't explain the behavior you are observing with MySQL, the demonstration code tests fine on both MySQL and MariaDb.  I tried to put it on sqlfiddle, but creating the trigger requires more memory than allocated, MySQL error "out of heap" or something. Same exact code works fine in my test environments.

Comment: The example I provided was a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger, That only executes when its "triggered" by an UPDATE statement that modifies a row in the table. To have these same (or similar) actions performed for an INSERT, we would need to create a BEFORE INSERT trigger.

Answer (score -1):

I had a same problem and I used two trigger,
First trigger send data to the other table, so now you can create another trigger to send this data to the first table. I think it is low performance but it is the only way that I reached to it. I hope others have another solution for u.

Comment: This sounds like it could be a little unstable; just make sure the second trigger doesn't retrigger the first trigger, or you may run into recursion issues.